# Can't compile Lua as C++

Tags: c++, cmake, lua

I'm trying to build Lua 5.4.3 (the latest release as of writing this) using the following CMakeLists.txt (and CMake 3.21) (ignore the fact that the target is called `lua_static` despite it being a shared lib):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(Lua LANGUAGES CXX)

# make cache variables for install destinations
include(GNUInstallDirs)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

set(LUA_LIB_SRCS 
    "src/ldblib.c"
    "src/ldebug.c"
    "src/ldo.c"
    "src/ldump.c"
    "src/lfunc.c"
    "src/lgc.c"
    "src/linit.c"
    "src/liolib.c"
    "src/lopcodes.c"
    "src/llex.c"
    "src/lmathlib.c"
    "src/lmem.c"
    "src/loadlib.c"
    "src/lobject.c"
    "src/loslib.c"
    "src/lparser.c"
    "src/lstate.c"
    "src/lstring.c"
    "src/lstrlib.c"
    "src/ltable.c"
    "src/ltablib.c"
    "src/ltm.c"
    "src/lundump.c"
    "src/lutf8lib.c"
    "src/lvm.c"
    "src/lzio.c"
    "src/lapi.c"
    "src/lauxlib.c"
    "src/lbaselib.c"
    "src/lcode.c"
    "src/lcorolib.c"
    "src/lctype.c"
)

set(LUA_HEADERS_INSTALL
    "src/lua.h"
    "src/luaconf.h"
    "src/lualib.h"
    "src/lauxlib.h"
    "src/lua.hpp"
)

# Compile directly as C++.
set_source_files_properties(${LUA_LIB_SRCS} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX )

add_library(lua_static SHARED ${LUA_LIB_SRCS})
set_target_properties(lua_static PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
set_target_properties(lua_static PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX d)

# make sure __cplusplus is defined when using msvc
if (MSVC)
    target_compile_options(lua_static PRIVATE /TP       # /TP doesn't is somehow stripped or ignored?
                                       /Zc:__cplusplus)
endif ()

target_include_directories(lua_static
                           PUBLIC
                           "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>"
)

install(TARGETS lua_static
        EXPORT lua_static_targets
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
        INCLUDES DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
)

install(FILES ${LUA_HEADERS_INSTALL} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})

install(EXPORT lua_static_targets
        FILE LuaStaticTargets.cmake
        NAMESPACE lua::
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/lua
)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

configure_package_config_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Config.cmake.in
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/LuaConfig.cmake"
  INSTALL_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/lua
)

install(FILES
          "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/LuaConfig.cmake"
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/lua
)
```

When building with MSVC, `__cplusplus` is defined and therefore I presume everything up until this point is working as intended. Then after installing, I link against the library like so

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(TestProject)

add_executable(Test Main.cpp)

# Lua
find_package(lua REQUIRED PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lua)
set_target_properties(lua::lua_static PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
target_link_libraries(Test lua::lua_static)
```

The reason why I want to compile Lua as C++ is to enable exceptions (rather than `longjmp`). So to test if exceptions would be thrown, I tried invoking one in this test program

```
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>

#include <iostream>

constexpr char* Test_Lua = R"(
function f (x, y)
      unknown()
      return 1/0
en
)";

lua_State* state;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    state = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(state);

    try
    {
        int error = luaL_loadbuffer(state, Test_Lua, strlen(Test_Lua), "Test");
        lua_call(state, 0, LUA_MULTRET); // Should thow, because of the syntax error
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception!" << std::endl;
        goto end;
    }

end:
    lua_close(state);
    return 0;
}
```

When stepping into `lua_call` with the debugger, I at some point end up in [ldo.c](https://www.lua.org/source/5.2/ldo.c.html) where Visual Studio indicates that `LUAI_THROW` is not defined via C++ exeption handling. This is because `__cplusplus` is not defined. Jumping to that source file in my Lua project files created earlier, `LUAI_THROW` was defined as desired. The fact that I can include the Lua headers suggests to me that the library has been compiled as a C++ library. In fact if I try to add `extern "C" { ... }`, I get linker errors.

Can someone shed some light on the cause of the problem?

---

Edit:

After looking more into the issue, I realized all compilation as C++ does, is that Lua **internally** handles functions that return error codes (such as `luaL_loadbuffer`) via exceptions. That doesn't mean I get to catch and handle them (which I originally thought). Functions like `lua_call` run in unprotected mode and thus call the panic function (see @bremen_matt's post).

Comment: Is LUA_USE_LONGJMP defined? It's also possible the IDE is wrong. You could put a #error statement in the longjmp block and see if it gets triggered when you compile

Comment: If you just run the code, do you see the `Exception` printed out?

Comment: If you just put a printout on the THROW macro, then you will know whether or not that line is being hit. For example: #define LUAI_THROW(L,c) (printf("THROWING"), throw(c))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know nothing about Lua. With that out of the way...

I think you are missing something with regards to how Lua is working internally. If I modify the macros in `ldo.c` at about line 57 to read:

```
#include <iostream>
#define LUAI_THROW(L,c) (fprintf(stderr, "THROWING\n"), throw(c))
#define LUAI_TRY(L,c,a) \
    try { a } catch(...) { fprintf(stderr, "CAUGHT\n"); if ((c)->status == 0) (c)->status = -1; }
```

Then when I run this, I see the output:

```
THROWING
CAUGHT
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to call a string value)
```

Which suggests that internally Lua is trying to run a snippet of code, catches the exception, and then exits without throwing another exception. Therefore, you as the user cannot catch this exception. It is being consumed inside of Lua.

Just a real quick look at the code suggests that maybe you want to use `lua_pcall`. It seems that the maybe the `p` means `protected`? and you can do some error handling with that? Either way, that function also does not seem to throw the error higher. It seems like you have to pass a function for error handling.

Comment: You're right. I added an edit to my original post. Thanks for the help!