# C++ Unresolved External Symbols Embedded Lua ( based on longjmp issue ) ( not duplicate )

Tags: c++, c, lua

I will describe the problem as follows:

Compiler: Visual Studio 2019

The root of the problem is that longjump crashes the process because I manually map my code to the process.

The code works fine as follows, but crashes on any syntax error in the lua script due to longjump:

```
extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
.....
}
```

I want C++ exceptions originating from:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus) && !defined(LUA_USE_LONGJMP) /* { */

/* C++ exceptions */
#define LUAI_THROW(L,c) throw(c)
#define LUAI_TRY(L,c,a) \
try { a } catch(...) { if ((c)->status == 0) (c)->status = -1; }
#define luai_jmpbuf int /* dummy variable */

#elif defined(LUA_USE_POSIX) /* }{ */

/* in POSIX, try _longjmp/_setjmp (more efficient) */
#define LUAI_THROW(L,c) _longjmp((c)->b, 1)
#define LUAI_TRY(L,c,a) if (_setjmp((c)->b) == 0) { a }
#define luai_jmpbuf jmp_buf

#else /* }{ */

/* ISO C handling with long jumps */
#define LUAI_THROW(L,c) longjmp((c)->b, 1)
#define LUAI_TRY(L,c,a) if (setjmp((c)->b) == 0) { a }
#define luai_jmpbuf jmp_buf

#endif /* } */
```

Because longjmp crashes my process.

So I decided to compile my code with the C++ compiler (without extern C) and:

```
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
.....
```

This is how I called it. But this also led to the following problem:
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_pcall
...
...
...

I thought a lot about it but couldn't find a solution.It's ridiculous that it's a linker error because all the lua header and c files are joined to my project.

Comment: I found this thread as similar issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68390401/cant-compile-lua-as-c

Comment: Not duplicate? How do you know? Please edit the question and add a *proof* of this truly extraordinary claim. "So I decided to compile my code with the C++ compiler (without extern C)". Why did you decide that this should work?

Comment: "So I decided to compile my code with the C++ compiler (without extern C)". Why did you decide that this should work? Coming to the part, the try catch block works fine for my code. but when I call longjmp or setjmp in the code even in a place independent of lua, I crash because (guess) I am far from tls. try catch block should work, it works.

Comment: As far as I can see, nothing whatsoever works with your code because you have a linker error. `extern "C"` is there for a reason. You removed it, and now wondering why you have an undefined reference. Because you removed  `extern "C"`, that's why.

Comment: http://lua-users.org/wiki/BuildingLua "Note on embedding Lua in C++ applications" lua can be compiled as c and c++. I guess you didn't understand my problem, to use try catch blocks I need to compile in c++. shouldn't I also extern from "c" for this?

Comment: Did you compile **Lua** (not just your application) as C++? Please show the complete unedited linker error.

Comment: Actually, im trying to figure out how to do it. When i am using it with "extern c" it was auto compiling with my project. Now when i compile it with my project it seems still compiling as C. How can i compile it as C++ ? Is there a setting on visual studio ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/tc-tp-tc-tp-specify-source-file-type?view=msvc-170

Comment: C2440 '=': 'void *' - 'char *' can not convert lvm.c 932

Comment: Yes, now I understand what you mean. also even SEH doesn't work for me. using lua in this case... i don't know, it crashes at the slightest syntax error. unable to debug. It contains huge problems. @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define LUAI_THROW(L,c) c->throwed = true
#define LUAI_TRY(L,c,a) \
    __try { a } __except(filter()) { if ((c)->status == 0 && ((c)->throwed)) (c)->status = -1; }
#define luai_jmpbuf     int  /* dummy variable */
```

Btw, i solved my throwing exception issue like that. Im not sure its correct or no but not crashing anymore.

```
struct lua_longjmp {
  struct lua_longjmp *previous;
  luai_jmpbuf b;
  volatile int status;  /* error code */
  bool throwed;
};
```

Works as expected even you build without C++ exceptions